# Tool to visually create a set of controls

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, controls, web

I'm looking for a tool, plugin or whatever that allows users to design a page (by "design a page" I mean just drag controls like input, select, radio to the page and define positioning by dragging them).
Once the user is done, I have to save the page and the controls to a serialized string, or XML, or JSON, or a .Net User Control.
The user-designed page will used as an input form for information, and I need to be able to set and get the field values somehow.

It's a complex topic even to search, no clues until now.

If someone can point me a direction, it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Sharepoint](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sharepoint&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharepoint.microsoft.com%2F&ei=ISWPT_mhKenN6QHH-rj9Dg&usg=AFQjCNE0TSMo-hti44WALbe8Y5LaRSY2dQ) lets you to build sites with web parts, that you can create and control theirs behavior.

With Sharepoint Web Parts, you can control its information and its fields.

Comment: hmm a solution that requires less effort would be better.. feels like riding a ferrari to cross the street. Any idea?

Comment: maybe a free - open source solution?